# Is this proof correct for $p_1\times p_2 \mod k = p_3$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that if $\gcd(p_1, k) = \gcd(p_2, k) = 1$, then $$\gcd(r,  k) = 1$$ where $r = p_1\times p_2  \mod k$. This fact is essential to guarantee that a unit group  $U(n)$ of a group $\Bbb Z_n$ is a group.

I tried proof by contradiction. Suppose $\gcd(r,k) \neq 1$. Then $r = a\gcd(r,k) \implies \gcd(r,k) | p_1 $ or $\gcd(r,k) | p_2$, which is a contradiction.

Is this a valid proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you do quite enough there, especially linking back to $p_1p_2$, although you could perhaps fix it up. You also seem to have implicitly that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime, which isn't really needed.

> Suppose $\gcd(r,k) =d \neq 1$. Then $r = ad, k = bd \implies p_1p_2 = q(bd)+ad = d(qb+a)$ so $p_1 \mid d $ or $p_2 \mid d$, which is a contradiction since $d \mid k$.

More comprehensively, without assuming that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime, you could appeal to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic:

> Since both $p_1$ and $p_2$ have no common prime factors with $k$, then also $p_1p_2$ has no common prime factors with $k$. Now $d=\gcd(r,k)$ divides both $r$ and $k$ and since $p1p2=ak+r$, $d$ must also divide $p_1p_2$, therefore no prime divides $d \implies d=1$.

Comment: I don't think I am quite assuming they are prime, I was just trying to say that they were relatively prime to $k$.

Comment: @SalmonKiller OK, then you can't say that one-or-the-other divides the gcd (or vice versa) - just that they have shared factors.

Comment: I see, because $4|4$ does not imply $4|2$.